# How to substring predefined variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Can I substring the predefined vscode variable ${fileDirname}?

Lets say fileDirname is "/home/your-username/your-project/folder".

In my case I would like to get "/home/your-username/your-project".

Currently my launch.json looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // ...
            "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "--runInBand",
                "--config",
                "> > > I would like to substring this: ${fileDirname}"
            ],
            // ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does `${workspaceFolder} ` work for you?

Comment: No, I really need a way to make a substring operation on ${fileDirname}